# RSYNC : exclude multiple files

Tags: rhel, rsync

I would like to sync two directories with excluding a few files. I tried below code but it fails in exclude.

```
FILES=abc.zip,hh.sh,Workarea/test/hi.jpg
rsync -av --exclude={$FILES} /home/test/ /home/test2
```

To verify it, i have executed as

```
# sh -x test.sh
+ FILES=abc.zip,hh.sh,Workarea/test/hi.jpg
+ rsync -av '--exclude={abc.zip,hh.sh,Workarea/test/hi.jpg}' /home/test/ /home/test2
```

Comment: Does the list of files need to be in a variable?

Comment: yes.. i will use it as runtime input..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't use the `bash` expansion `{a,b,c}` as anything other than a literal (you can't put `a,b,c` or even `{a,b,c}` in a variable and have it expanded directly. You could use `eval` but that opens up lots of unexpected complications, and I really do not recommend it:

```
FILES=abc.zip,hh.sh,Workarea/test/hi.jpg
eval rsync -av --exclude={$FILES} /home/test/ /home/test2    # Don't do this!
```

> *Anything is fine*

Here's a better alternative suggestion for you, which uses the `bash` array feature to hold the set of exclusions. We then build up the command line for `rsync` by iterating across it.

```
files=(abc.zip hh.sh Workarea/test/hi.jpg "Some file with a space in its name")

excludes=()
for f in "${files[@]}"
do
    excludes+=(--exclude "$f")
done
rsync -av "${excludes[@]}" /home/test/ /home/test2
```